# How to use app bundle of android on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, app-bundle

I have an Android app developed by Flutter.

Question

- Can I reduce the size of the ram through the app bundle?
- If not, plan to support the app bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for app bundle is **added**. Check this PR [#24440](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/24440)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Unfortunately there is no integration for Android App Bundle (aab) in Flutter yet. But it is a requested feature, so we might see it sooner or later. You can find more information regarding that in the [GitHub issue 17829](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17829).</strike>

Also you can find requested features in the GitHub repo under milestones. The current milestones can be found under [milestone #22](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/milestone/22).

**EDIT 19/3/2:**
Android App Bundle is now available with the [latest commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/24440). You may need to update to the master branch to use it.